# Keyboard incorrectly mapped when using Open NX

Tags: keyboard, nx

I seem to be having keyboard issues on Ubuntu 11.04. Recently I tried to remote in to my machine using OpenNX (http://opennx.net/) and found that my keyboard incorrectly mapped on the client machine. Now, after coming back to my host machine and attempting to use it they keyboard reacts the same way as through the OpenNX client.

What's happening is the 's' key is mapped to the 'o' key, return is mapped to '8', and so on. Any suggestions on what to try?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The OpenNX client should have a setting to decide which keyboard layout you wish to use. Nomachines client does and OpenNX is supposed to be an open replacement, if I recall correctly. Look for it in the session preferences.